# Setting explicit width of flexible NSView that has greater-than and less-than constraints

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, autolayout, appkit

How do you explicitly set the width of an NSView that already has constraints dictating its minimum width and its maximum width?

For example, consider an `NSSplitView` embedded in a window. In the left pane of the split view is an `Inspector` while in the right pane is just some content:

```
---------------------------------
|             |                 | <- NSSplitView
|             |                 |
| Inspector   |  Content        |
|             |                 |
|             |                 |
|             |                 |
---------------------------------

---------------------------------
|                               |
|                               |
|          Content              |
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
---------------------------------
```

The `Inspector` has two constraints on it:

- `width >= 200.0 @ 1000`
- `width <= 400.0 @ 1000`

The only constraints on the split view are ones that allow it to fill its superview and the `Content` view only as constraints to fill its superview as well (the right-side splitter pane).

When this view is created, I'd like to set the initial width of the `Inspector` to a dynamic value (something that was saved in the user's preferences, perhaps).

But if I just naïvely do something like:

- `width = 320.0 @ 1000`

Then the split view will no longer allow that view to be resized. Values of `499` and `749` also cause the same problem. If I lower the priority to something like:

- `width = 320.0 @ 250`

Then the split view will resize, but its initial pane width is not `320.0` but rather `400.0`, as set laid-out in Interface Builder.

The ultimate goal is to allow the `Inspector` to be both resized within a given range, but to also be hidden or collapsed entirely (of which I was hoping to just set the `width` to `0`, and the `minWidth` constraint to `0` as well).

I suspect I could go down and handle this manually in `[layout]` but I'm curious if there's a way to accomplish this entirely with constraints.

(Note: Most of this layout is being done in Interface Builder but I'm quite happy to handle the constraints programmatically if need-be. 10.8+ is fine as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [-[NSSplitView setAutosaveName:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Classes/NSSplitView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSplitView/setAutosaveName%3a) to have NSSplitView do the work to save the user's preference and then load that as the initial width on startup?

---

If you didn't want to go that route, you could do something pretty similar to your first instinct.

After you add the `width = 320.0 @ 1000` constraint, you want to layout your window, `[window layoutIfNeeded]`, and then remove that constraint.

Your Inspector view will have the updated frame, but the constraint forcing it to be there will be gone, allowing the view to be resized.

Comment: The problem with `setAutosaveName` is that I want to be able to programmatically toggle the inspector any number of times after the app has launched. Without constraints it's just a matter of configuring the `frame` as appropriate, but I'm trying to use constraints at the moment. It hadn't dawned on me to remove the width constraint immediately after forcing a layout. I just tried a quick test and that sort of works, when the width constant is equal to minWidth or maxWidth, but for any other value the view snaps back to minWidth each time.

Comment: The snap back are likely because of the holding priorities that the splitView sets on the views to keep them the size they are. Have you changed these yet (e.g. to make the content resize with the window, rather than the inspector)?  If you want the constraint you add to stick around, try to make the constraint have a priority of higher than the holding priorities', but less than 499 like you mentioned. This should allow that constraint to determine the width, yet still allow dragging by the user. Make sure to update it as they drag or it will jump back afterwards.

Comment: I haven't quite gotten the perfect combination of priorities and constraints, but your hint at adding and removing constraints as needed clearly set me down the right path, so I'm marking this as the answer for me. The specifics of which steps I'll take are somewhat context dependent, but the general idea of dynamically adding and removing constraints should work for me. Thanks.